# fputs() producing wrong result

Tags: c, fputs

My code is producing incorrect result. I don't know why.

When I give the length as 5 and enter the string as "vasanth", this should produce "vasan" as output. But it gives output as "vasa".

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main(){
    int n;
    printf("Enter the length of the string : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    getchar();
    char array[n];
    fgets(array, n, stdin);
    fputs(array, stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `vasa` plus NUL terminator makes 5 characters. That is the array size, not the string length.

Comment: How can I rectify this error? @WeatherVane

Comment: @VASANTHKUMARG change the array size to `n+1`.

Comment: A tip: the majority of the time, when you call `fgets`, you pass an array and a size comfortably longer than the longest line you can imagine that the user might type.  If you want to make sure the user types a string that's under some limit, `fgets` is not the way to enforce it.  The size argument you pass to `fgets` is there so that `fgets` can promise not to overflow the array -- but it's *not* intended for data validation.  If you want to do data validation, let the user type any string, then call `strlen()`, then complain if it's too long.

Answer (score 2):

The last element is reserved for a terminating null-character. Allocate one more element to fix.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int n;
    printf("Enter the length of the string : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    getchar();
    char array[n+1];
    fgets(array, n+1, stdin);
    fputs(array, stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

Quote from [N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) 7.21.7.2 The fgets function:

> 2
> The fgets function reads at most one less than the number of characters specified by n
> from the stream pointed to by stream into the array pointed to by s. No additional
> characters are read after a new-line character (which is retained) or after end-of-file. A
> null character is written immediately after the last character read into the array.

Here you will find that the number of characters to read is *at most one less than* the specified `n`.